# I want to stop the Do Until loop when I click the Cancel button

Tags: vb.net

I want to stop the Do...Until loop when I click the "Cancel" button.

How to do that?

Here my code:

```
If Db_Connection() = False Then
    Dim Response, Msg, Style, Title As String
    Msg = "DataBase Connection Error Occured"
    Style = vbRetryCancel Or vbCritical Or vbDefaultButton1
    Title = "Connection Error"
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)

    If Response = vbRetry Then
        'Retry for database connection
        Do Until Db_Connection() = True
            MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
            While Response = vbCancel
                Exit Do
            End While

        Loop

        MsgBox("Connection Was Established", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "DataBase Connection")

    End If
Else
    If status = False Then
        MsgBox("Station Name Or Station Code Already Exists", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion, "Repeat Data")

    End If

End If
```

Comment: `MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)` is missing the `response = `. Also, convention is for local variable names to start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: That's not how it works. What are you actually trying to achieve, functionality-wise. If we know that then we can tell you how you should be doing it.

Comment: Please note that you should not create one DB connection for the lifetime of the program. That is an anti-pattern for the modern usage of DB connections. Instead, create a connection to use with a query and once the query is done, call `.Dispose()` on the connection. That is how it is made to work best.

Comment: Also, you ***really*** need to set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and set it as the default for new projects) so that Visual Studio is allowed to point out problems in the code for you, and suggest fixes.

Comment: What condition(s) would prevent a DB connection being established? Perhaps it would be better to check for those before trying to create the connection.

Comment: This looks more like vb6/vbscript than vb.net. VB.Net is idiomatically a very different language, and while lots of the older vbscript paradigms will work, you're left with sub-optimal results and some things that are legitimate bugs if you try to use it that way.